# how to remove wp-stats malware in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, statistics, blocking, malware

In my wordpress the follwing code added automatically in the footer.

```
<script src="http://stats.wordpress.com/e-201319.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
st_go({v:'ext',j:'1:1.2.2',blog:'31704568',post:'0'});
var load_cmc = function(){linktracker_init(31704568,0,2);};
if ( typeof addLoadEvent != 'undefined' ) addLoadEvent(load_cmc);
else load_cmc();
</script>
```

Also i can found wp-counts.php and wp-apps.php in the folder.
The google block the website due to the malware code.

I cant able to clear this malware, since i was new to wordpress can anyone help me to clear this issue.

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: any problem with this code?

Comment: google blocked the website "Warning - visiting this web site may harm your computer!"

Comment: In webmaster tools it shows suspect injected code "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://lasertuck.c
om/news/default-php-version.php">". I cant able to find where it was injected. Help

Answer (score 0):

Go to Securi.com and run their scan on your site.  You may also want to sign up for their server scan and cleanup service.

Check the modification times of files on your system, looking for any that have been changed since you installed Wordpress.

Be sure to check your workstation for malware that might be monitoring your use of FTP and change your FTP passwords.

Comment: run a virus scanner, check your router logs or put a sniffer on your ethernet connection and see if something is calling out to a site you don't recognize, consult a security expert.